# Internal hard disk requirements will not allow me to update to Maverick

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, hard-drive, software-update

I tried to update to Mavericks, downloaded the update through App Store but the installation stalled with an error message saying my internal hdd didn't meet requirements.   I'm using an iMac mid 2007 core 2 duo with the Western Digital 320Gb drive.

Confusion has arisen due to my prior installation/update of Mavericks over one of my backup clones connected via firewire 800 - which is a doggy old IDE drive in an ancient icecube enclosure, and it works really well!!

So thinking that I might just clone my working external Mavericks to my internal drive, kick it in the guts and see how things work out - and it didn't.  Sat on the initial grey startup screen for 15 minutes before I got bored with the spinner and rebooted back to my working system.   What is going on?  I haven't been able to find any reference to required hdd specifications in documentation.  If my only option is to upgrade my internal disk then I will do it.  I was just just struck by the oddness of the refusal to ran on a particular disk.

My question is: Can I do anything about this reluctance to upgrade on my WDC WD3200AAJS?

Comment: Can you show us the boot messages? You can press [Command-V](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/723/mac-os-x-monitor-messages-during-boot/) during boot to view them. Maybe this will display an error message. Most probably you will then have to upgrade your hard disk...

Answer (score 1):

Usually when there's a problem with upgrading you have to "re-bless" the HDD. This often comes from a permissions problem with something on the HDD. You can open the Disk Utility and do a full permissions check to find any problems.

In my experience I've found the best way to accomplish this is to create a boot-able USB device using something like "Disk Maker X" and then boot from that. Once in the installer Open the Utilities and run Disk Utility from there. This will allow the permissions to be accessed from outside the disk, which helps since you won't have anything dependent on your log in. After the permissions are fully repaired try rebooting to the USB device and re-installing.